# Python- Bokeh - DataCube - Not able to select any row and extract information through callback

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am able to do that same thing with DataTable where clicking on a given row triggers callback using source.selected.on_change() however this doesnt seem to work for DataCube

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh 2.0.2, this functionality is not implemented at all. Please feel free to create a feature request on Bokeh's GitHub page.

Comment: Okay, so there is no support for DataCube even though the same functionality is available for DataTable right ?

Comment: Unclear what you men by "no support for DataCube". `DataCube` is supported by Bokeh. But `DataCube` itself does not support selection change notifications right now.